# Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space solr

Tags: solr

We are getting below error while running feed from web server to solr

**Error:**
 [ERROR 17-07-24:07:13:55] Error 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Java: jdk1.7.0_71
tomcat: apache-tomcat-6.0.36

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#Java_Heap

Comment: Do you have some more informations for us? Like the context in which you use it/what kind and what amount of data you have indexed :)